# Can I use the python speech_recognition and openAI's whisper libraries together to transcribe speech to text from my microphone?

Tags: speech-recognition, openai-whisper

Im trying to use speech recognition to record audio and then use whisper to transcribe that audio. Ideally id like to do this without saving to a file but im not sure if this is possible.

Ive tried doing this already but with no luck,

The code below does not work, Ive been getting "no such file or directory errors", but id like to avoid having to save the audio data to a file if possible

```
def whisper_listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()  # initialize a recognizer object
    with sr.Microphone() as source:  # use the microphone
        print("Speak Anything :")
        audio = r.listen(source)  # record the audio, store in audio wav file
        file = open("audio.wav", "r+")
        file.write(audio)
    transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", file) #transcribe the wav file with openAI's whisper bot
    return transcript
```

The code below works, but its not great and id like to try whisper as everything ive read seems to say its better than googles recognizer. Ideally id like to replicate what im doing below but just substitute the recognize_google line for something with whisper, but after some searching I cant seem to find how to do this.

````
def listener():
    ''' listen to the users speech to determine what the next step should be'''
    r = sr.Recognizer()  # initialize a recognizer object
    with sr.Microphone() as source:  # use the microphone
        print("Speak Anything :")
        audio = r.listen(source)  # record the audio, store in audio wav file
        try:
            text = r.recognize_google(audio)  # use google ai to recognize the recorded audio
            print("You said : {}".format(text))
        except:
            print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
            text = "write me some code to print hello world"
    return text```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!
````

Answer (score 1):

The [Speech Recognition library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) supports Whisper.

You should use the function `recognize_whisper()` instead.

Comment: Saddly, speech_recognition is today (8.2.24) not compatible with recent versions (past 1.0) of openai pythons libs :(

Comment: Interesting @Blitz - do you have more information on the incompatibilities?

Comment: `recognize_whisper` is using a local whisper model for transcription -- `openai.Audio.transcriptions.create` can use a remote OpenAI, AzureOpenAI, AzureAI or otherwise self-hosted instance. The similarly named `recognize_azure` uses the Microsoft Azure Speech API instead.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import speech_recognition as sr
from openai import OpenAI

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
 print("Say something!")
 audio = r.listen(source)
print ("Processing...")
client = OpenAI()
with open("microphone-results.wav", "wb") as f:
 f.write(audio.get_wav_data())

with open("microphone-results.wav", "rb") as f:
 transcript = client.audio.transcriptions.create(
 model="whisper-1", 
 file=f,
 response_format="text",
 )
 print(transcript)
```

You were/are missing reopening the file in read mode. Found no better way to handle it, temp files don't work saddly.

Comment: sadly the only way I've got it to work as well. I'm getting back `Error 424 - Unrecognized file format` instead otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Instade of calling the openai api endpoint you can you the inbuilt method here.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path

AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "test.wav")


r = sr.Recognizer()

# use the audio file as the audio source
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

# for microphone
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)


try:
    print(r.recognize_whisper(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Did not understand")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print(e)
```

Do not use both the microphone and the audio reader together